# update a postgres table column value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have one offset date to be stored in Postgres table -

```
latest_mod_date = max(data['last_modified'])

latest mod_date = 2022-04-16 05:50:00
```

Want this date to be updated in postgres -

Used this query -
The postgres table data_offset is like this -

```
_id offset_type offset_value    
    1     C          [NULL] 
    2     P          [NULL] 


# # query to update - global is the schema and data_offset is the data table in postgres

sql = '''update global.data_offset set {offset_value=latest_mod_date} where {offset_type='C'}; '''
#
# # execute the query
cursor.execute(sql)
print("Table updated..")

print('Table after updation...')

# query to display table
sql2 = 'select * from global.data_offset;'

# execute query
cursor.execute(sql2);

# fetching all details
print(cursor.fetchall());
```

This query is giving error -

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: update global.data_offset set {offset_value=latest_mo...
```

I want the latest_mod_date to be stored in the offset value where the offset_stypr is 'C'.

Comment: why do you have brackets `{}` in the query ? I've never seen that

Comment: I referred few posts where brackets were there, can you please help me with the solution https://stackoverflow.com/users/7212686/azro

Comment: Can you share at least one page where they show the brackets ? Also in betwee, try without the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Any place you have seem `{}` is probably because people have been doing something like `sql_str.format()` which is the wrong thing to do. See [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for the correct way to pass variables in.

In your case what you need is:

```
sql = "update global.data_offset set offset_value = %s where offset_type='C'"

cursor.execute(sql, [latest_mod_date])

# Commit the changes.
con.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks , but the data is not updated in the Postgres table rather I can see the sql output with updated date. Can you please tell why? https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver

Comment: At some point you have to do `con.commit()` where `con` is the connection you created earlier. Without a `commit` the change will not perssist.

Comment: Thanks, it worked out. I am facing another error - psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
 This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 before or while processing the request.                                                                             Can you please help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver

Comment: That is a different issue, create a new question with the Postgres version, the command you where running when the error occurred and relevant information from the Postgres log. Also if the solution worked will accept the answer?